# cant install express.js on windows 10 using git bash

Tags: javascript, express

npm install -g express-generator

> npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT npm ERR! network
>   request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express-generator failed,
>   reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.120.162:443 npm ERR! network This is
>   a problem related to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most
>   cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings. npm ERR!
>   network npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure
>   that the npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm
>   help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a proxy you need to configure your npm configurations as follows :

```
npm config set proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://<username>:<password>@<proxy-server-url>:<port>
```

Once you have set these, your npm install, npm i -g etc. would work properly.

You can find your proxy setting in chrome advanced parameters.